# Hide headers and variables in inspector from parent classes in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a class "Weapon" and a subclass "ThrowableWeapon". I want to hide in the inspector of the second one some variables and headers that were inherited from the parent. Is it possible?

I also would like to modify the default values of some public variables from the parent and show the new values as default in the inspector of the child, but I can't see how to do that. If I change the value inside the Start method of the child, the default value in the inspector is still the parent's default value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide the parent's serialized fields, you will have to create a [Custom inspector](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/building-custom-inspector) and retrieve the fields of your derived class.

If you want to "override" the default value in the derived class, the only way I could think about is to implement the [MonoBehaviour's `Reset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Reset.html) function and set the desired values here.

> Reset is called when the user hits the Reset button in the Inspector's context menu or when adding the component the first time. This function is only called in editor mode. Reset is most commonly used to give good default values in the inspector.

```
void Reset()
{
    parentAttribute = newValue ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Hellium!